# Connecting to Truffle local network through Metamask

Tags: truffle, metamask, rpc

After launching Truffle in the "(develop)" view, I've tried to connect to it through Metamask (via the "Custom RPC" option in the "Networks" menu, I've set the URI to "http://127.0.0.1:9545").

Then, I've tried to import into Metamask the mnemonic phrase that Truffle gave me upon launching, but this gave me access to only 2 of the 10 accounts that Truffle created. Also, those 2 accounts don't have a balance of 100 ETH (as they should): the first account has a balance which changes costantly, but never goes below 200k ETH or above 260k ETH, while the other account has always a balance of 0 ETH.

Furthermore, interactions through a simple web-app that I've created for testing purposes don't seem to change the state of the corresponding smart contract or the amount of ether assigned to the first account, which makes me think that my web browser isn't correctly communicating with the local instance provided by Truffle.
What piece of the puzzle am I missing?

EDIT: Here's the significant snippets of code of the web-app (I'm using web3 API in React).

```
function App() {

  const [web3] = useState(new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "http://localhost:9545"));
  const [contract] = useState(new web3.eth.Contract(TODO_ABI, TODO_ADDRESS));
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    contract.methods.getTasks().call()
      .then(tasks => {

        setTasks(tasks);
      });

  }, [contract.methods]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <TaskForm contract={contract}></TaskForm>
      <TasksList tasks={tasks} contract={contract}></TasksList>
    </div>
  );
}

function TaskForm(props) {

  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  return(
    <form onSubmit={ () => setContent(event.target.value) }>
      <input type="text" onChange={ () => props.contract.methods.addTask(content).call() }></input>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}

function ChangeTaskStateButton(props) {

  return (
    <button onClick={ () => props.contract.methods.changeTaskState(props.id).call() }>{ props.state }</button>
  );
}
```

And here's the errors that gets displayed when trying to close a task:

```
inpage.js:1 MetaMask - RPC Error: Internal JSON-RPC error. 
{code: -32603, message: "Internal JSON-RPC error.", data: {…}}
code: -32603
data: {message: "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert", code: -32000, data: {…}}
message: "Internal JSON-RPC error."
__proto__: Object



index.js:50 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Internal JSON-RPC error.
{
  "message": "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert",
  "code": -32000,
  "data": {
    "0x359c33ac64b2b3eb0096b40b2d225679d4212f40fc86ef938af49fcc47159f2c": {
      "error": "revert",
      "program_counter": 994,
      "return": "0x4e487b710000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000032"
    },
    "stack": "RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert\n    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (C:\\Users\\gianm\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\utils\\runtimeerror.js:94:1)\n    at C:\\Users\\gianm\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\truffle\\build\\webpack:\\node_modules\\ganache-core\\lib\\blockchain_double.js:568:1",
    "name": "RuntimeError"
  }
}
    at Object._fireError (index.js:50)
    at sendTxCallback (index.js:540)
    at cb (util.js:689)
    at callbackifyOnRejected (util.js:666)
    at Item.push../node_modules/process/browser.js.Item.run (browser.js:153)
    at drainQueue (browser.js:123)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can import 10 accounts by Private Key.
2. Check your port, shouldn't the default be 8545?
3. ETH balance display error: need to 'Settings - Network - Symbol' to fill in the ETH, although it is optional, but need to fill in the ETH

Comment: Solved the balance problem, so that's good. However, my webapp still doesn't seem to be communicating properly with my contract.
Right after executing "truffle develop", I get the message "Truffle Develop started at http://127.0.0.1:9545/". Also, connection attempts to port 8545 are unsuccessful anyway.
What's weird is that my app allows for two types of transactions: 1) adding a new task to the list corresponding to the address currently in use, 2) closing a task (I've added the code to the first post). Adding a task SEEMS like it's working:

Comment: it doesn't cause any error to appear in the browser's console and the task then gets displayed on the page. However, the balance of the account that requested the transaction doesn't change, and checking the tasks list of the corresponding address in the smart contract reveals that it is still empty. Conversely, closing a task just flat out doesn't work and causes two errors to be displayed in the browser's console (added those to the first post as well).

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the contract

Comment: I doubt it, It compiles successfully and when I interact with it through the truffle develop console, it works exactly as intended. I very much think it is a clientside problem. I just can't figure out what problem it is. I checked out a bunch of basic dapp tutorials to see if I did something wrong, but they all do what I did, I'm pretty confused. I even tried using a different browser, but nothing. I'm really weirded out, especially because the calls to the contract that I use to retrieve the tasks and to add a new task don't cause any errors to be diplayed, they just silently don't work

Comment: To be more specific, it actually seems like the communication with those functions is successful. For example, the function to fetch the tasks returns something: an empty array. However, if I add a task through the terminal ( (await ToDo.deployed()).addTask("Hello World") ) and then I request the list of the tasks from the terminal  as well ( (await ToDo.deployed()).getTasks() ), I then get an array of length 1 containing the task that I just added, but the web app keeps on fetching an empty array no matters what.

Comment: Don't know if the fact that it returns an empty array means anything. Maybe it knows through the ABI (which is local to the webapp) that it should be returning an array and returns an empty array by default or something?

Comment: I think you must have a problem in some step, but I can't predict the specific, maybe it is a very simple problem

Comment: I've actually solved this problem eventually. Turns out that it was an extremely newbie mistake that I'm kind of ashamed of: I was using the call() method to invoke some of the smart contract's functions that weren't read only, should've use send(). Also learnt that it is better to use the Ethereum Provider API (request() and such) in order to do such things. Thanks all for your help anyway! And sorry for the basically useless post.

Comment: Come on, we make progress together!

Answer (score 0):

I just did all the Metamask set up with `truffle develop`, and everything works fine. Just to be sure:

1. Network ID must be `1337`. You can obtain it by running `web3.eth.getChainId()` in the terminal.
2. Port is `9545`.
3. You can add further addresses by clicking `Create account`. Up to the 10th they will have funds (100 ETH by default).
4. You are using `.call()` when invoking methods that modify the state. That will perform a simulation of the logic and return the result, if any, but won't modify the state. Make sure you only use `.call()` when invoking read-only methods.